# sfDoctrineGuard - get only groups logged in user is a member of

Tags: symfony1, sfdoctrineguard

I have a table that has a sfGuardGroup column so when a user logs in, they can only see the records users in their group have made.

When creating a record I want to have a select box for the sfGuardGroup that only contains the groups that the logged in user is a member of.

Anyone know how to do this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the form::configure

1. get user: use sfContex::getInstance()->getUser() (easy way, not recommend) or inject sfUser from controller as option

   $this->form = new myAwesomeUserForm(array(),array('user'=>$this->getUser()));
2. Use sfWidgetFormChoice
3. Use sfGuardSecurityUser::getGroups ($user->getGroups) to set choices for sfWidgetFormChoice widget. Here $user is instance of myUser>sfGuardSecurityUser
4. Do not forget validator

Comment: Thanks for replying, sorry if I sound a bit dumb, but is this what you mean: [code]  public function configure()
  {
 $user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser();
 $this->widgetSchema['sfGuardGroup'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => sfGuardSecurityUser::getGroups($user->getGroups), 'add_empty' => false));
  }[code]

Comment: almost yes. You do not need to use sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice, Just use  sfWidgetFormChoice

Comment: I am getting the error
`code` Strict Standards: Non-static method sfGuardSecurityUser::getGroups() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\DSMS\lib\form\doctrine\slideForm.class.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined property: myUser::$getGroups in C:\xampp\htdocs\DSMS\lib\form\doctrine\slideForm.class.php on line 16 `code`

Is it right that I'm putting it in lib\form\doctrine\***Form.class.php ?

Comment: You should use $user->getGroups() method.

Comment: it gets all the groups that the user is in now, however it won't save, it says sfGuardGroup is invalid

Comment: Please show some of your current code, configuring the form widget and best resulting html form template.